# How can I read values updated by javascript

Tags: java, javascript, dom

I want to parse an html page using org.w3c.dom package. Let it be http://www.qypedeals.de/. The page has a counter updated by JS So if I try to get a value of

```
    <div class='counter_field' id='counter_day'>
```

I always get 0. Is there any possibility to get that value?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to get you on your way, unless you send that data to the server (form element?) then the server cannot let you read that value. Sounds like it's time for some learning of the inner workings of HTML form elements and post values...

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want the end date. If so line 421 (probably, I do not know german)

Comment: You need to figure out where that value is coming from.  In some spot it is conveyed from the qypedeals.de server to the browser, and then applied to the display in js.  Retrieve whatever contains the value.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
alert(document.getElementById('counter_day').innerHTML)
```

Comment: it is a div - so document.getElementById('counter_day').innerHTML :)

Answer (score 0):

How about `document.getElementById("counter_day").parentNode.text` ?
Or `document.getElementById("counter_day").parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')`

Can the package handle that?